# Collecting assorted values from nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Synopsis: Clicking on "Great Things!" opens a modal populated with values obtained within various elements nested under a specified ID. ...At least privately, on my computer, in development.

Why does the following work locally and not on the server? What alternate options might I research in order to achieve online what works so beautifully in my secluded WAMP environment? Better yet, what slam dunk solution would remedy this half-working endeavor?

I've read about origin policy and the find() method and understand this is a PEBCAK issue (aren't they all?) as I brace for humiliation.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-role=doThis]', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var foo = $('#' + id).find('a[data-target=xyz]').attr('href');
  var bar = $('#' + id).find('[data-target=lmnop]').text();
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

  // assign above values to these ID's inside 'myModal'
  $('#idTwo').val(foo);
  $('#idThree').val(bar);

  modal.style.display = "block";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-role="doThis" data-id="123">Great Things!</a>

<div id="123">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="http://url.com" data-target="xyz">Hello World</a>
      <span data-target="lmnop">More questions than answers</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="myModal">
  <input type="text" id="idTwo">
  <input type="text" id="idThree">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the actual issue when i checked rendering i found on these lines:

```
var foo = $('#'+id).find('a[data-target=xyz]').attr('href');
var bar = $('#'+id).find('[data-target=lmnop]').text();
```

there are missing double quotes which gives  `Syntax error, unrecognized expression:a[data-target=xyz]`

Try using below lines:

```
var foo = $('#'+id).find('a[data-target="xyz"]').attr('href');
var bar = $('#'+id).find('[data-target="lmnop"]').text();
```

Comment: Arghh... The surge of excitement was quickly met with a blunt smack of defeat. That continues to work locally but not on the server.

Answer (score 0):

For whomever this might help - Upon viewing the source code and running a Find on the ID, it was found 2 times. For some reason this didn't matter locally but on the server it did. Suffice it to say - basic user error!